# How do I get the label to display an int?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm following a tutorial using Xcode 8.3 and Swift language. This tutorial we're making an app where you input a number (age of your cat) in the text field, press the button, it gets multiplied by 7 then it displays (cat age in cat years) on the label. I followed the instructions exactly but the label isn't changing or updating when I press the button. I'm sure that the label is connected, I'm use that I'm using the right variable names. I don't know what's wrong.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var ageTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var ageLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let ageInCatYears = Int(ageTextField.text!)! * 7

        ageLabel.text = String(ageInCatYears)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Siyavash What do you mean by delegates? I connected the text field to the view controller. Sorry for the basic question! I'm really just a beginner at all this.

Comment: Have you tried to add a breakpoint or print something inside that @IBAction? Is it calling? If yes, what values if the textfield are you getting?

Comment: Please make sure again that label is connected and print(ageInCatYears) in button action and see if you are getting the right value?

Comment: have you connected your IBOutlets and IBActions ?  Tapping on the button, the IBAction method gets executed?  and make sure you are entering integer value in text field.

Comment: FYI - if you are following a tutorial that teaches you to use so many `!` operators then you need a better tutorial.

Comment: put a `print(ageInCatYears)` inside your `buttonTapped(_:)` function and see whether it prints in the console or not.

Comment: @user1000 I tried print(ageInCatYears) and nothing is showing up on the console...

Comment: @nayem Okay I tried it and nothing is printing in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add print(ageTextField.text) and see if it prints, what you enter in textfield?

Comment: code works fine did you try reconnecting Outlets again ?

Comment: Then definitely you haven't connected the `@IBAction` to the `Button` in your storyboard.

Comment: Check the `@IBAction` and `@IBOutlet`. I have run you code and its working.

Comment: @user1000 Nothing is displaying on the console. Another user suggested I haven't connected IBAction to the button. I'll try making the app again.

Comment: @nayem Okay, I'll try making this again and make sure they're connected.

Comment: it's is probably workable

Comment: @newbieIOS Instead of editing your question with your solution, you should accept the answer that best solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

First check whether you have correctly hooked up IBOutlets and ABActions from Storyboard to your ViewController. Open `Storyboard -> Select ViewController -> Open Assistant Editor -> Connect Outlets and IBAction`.

One more thing use [if let](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-unwrap-an-optional-in-swift) to unwrap your text

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
   if let num = ageTextField.text, let age = Int(age) {
     let ageInCatYears = age * 7
     ageLabel.text = String(ageInCatYears)
   }
}
```

[image: Connecting ButtonTapped Action via IBAction]

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on your controller in the interface builder.
2. Click on the connections inspector
3. Check that all of your outlets and actions are connected

[image]

Comment: Okay I checked it and made sure they're all connected, it works now. Thank you!